# How to extract particular columns values from multiple rows using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model class like this.

```
Public Class SampleModel
{
    public string ItemName{ get; set; }
    public string ItemNo{ get; set; }
    public int ItemQty{ get; set; }
    public string GroupName{ get; set; }
    public int Group1 { get; set; }
    public int Group2 { get; set; }
    public int Group3 { get; set; }
    public int Group4 { get; set; }
}
```

The Table Contains the values for first 4 ItemName,ItemNo,ItemQty and GroupName.
for each ItemNo are having 4 rows and only ItemQty  will be differ which is entered by each groupName(Group1Count ,Group2Count ,Group3Count ,GroupCount ).

Table content like this .

```
ItemName    ItemNo  ItemQty GroupName
Pen           234    2        Group1 
Pen           234    4        Group2
Pen           234    6        Group3
Pen           234    3        Group4
item2         365    3        Group1 
item2         365    5        Group2
item2         365    2        Group3
item2         365    3        Group4
item3         370    3        Group1
item3         370    2        Group4
item4         372    6        Group2
item4         372    9        Group4
```

so i am getting all the values using this query.

```
var data= from a in context.Batch where a.GroupName != "" select a;
```

from this again i need filter out based on the combination of ItemName,ItemNo,ItemQty and show the result like this.

```
ItemName    ItemNo  Group1  Group2  Group3  Group4 
Pen          234      2       4       6       3
item2        365      3       5       2       3
item3        370      3       0       0       2
item4        372      0       6       0       9
```

Please suggest me how to write a linq query for this.

Comment: You are building a Pivot Table.  You are lucky that you have a fixed number of groups.  Most Pivot Table solutions the number of groups is not fixed and a more complicated solution is required.

Comment: even am not so lucky as well. here that Group Name may goes to any number of values. Group1 ,Group2 ...... Group10 etc..

Comment: The I would change class to public List<int> Groups { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
    var list=context.Batch.GroupBy(x=>new{x.ItemName,x.ItemNo})
                          .Select(x=>new
                          {
                                  ItemName=x.Key.ItemName,
                                  ItemNo=x.Key.ItemNo,
                                  Group1=x.Where(y=>y.GroupName=="Group1").FirstOrDefault(),
                                  Group2=x.Where(y=>y.GroupName=="Group2").FirstOrDefault(),
                                  Group3=x.Where(y=>y.GroupName=="Group3").FirstOrDefault(), 
                                  Group4=x.Where(y=>y.GroupName=="Group4").FirstOrDefault() 
                           })
                         .Select(x=> new SampleModel{
                                  ItemName=x.ItemName,
                                  ItemNo=x.ItemNo,
                                  Group1=x.Group1==null?0:x.Group1.ItemQty,
                                  Group2=x.Group2==null?0:x.Group2.ItemQty,
                                  Group3=x.Group3==null?0:x.Group3.ItemQty,
                                  Group4=x.Group4==null?0:x.Group4.ItemQty

                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: At run time getting this Exception : Sequence contains no elements even though context.Batch has all the values.

Comment: Could please the syntax in this line. Group1=x.Where(y=>y.GroupName=="Group1").FirstOrDefault()==null 0:x.Where(y=>y.GroupName=="Group1").FirstOrDefault().ItemQty,

Comment: I updated the answer. In this variant, I select groups from database in first Select statement, after that, in second Select statement, I check group values with ternary operator. The meaning of this statement (**x.Group1==nul?0:x.Group1**) is that, it checks group1 value. If value is null then it returns 0, if not it returns its value.

Comment: Sorry! i got the ternary operator usage but again the itemQty is missing. I am using Odata Service to get the data from Database(Microsoft Dynamic Nav). so first i am getting the resutl to List<SampleModel> . then i am trying to extract the the data from it

Comment: @RajeswariML Can you check?

Comment: on the first Select                                                                 var list=context.Batch.GroupBy(x=>new{x.ItemName,x.ItemNo})
                          .Select(x=>x new facing some syntax error. trying to fix that.

Comment: that was syntax error. I updated my answer. Places check

Comment: Total 18 records are there with 9 different batch. so this much code works fine and getting 9 records.  **var list=context.Batch.GroupBy(x=>new{x.ItemName,x.ItemNo})
                          .Select(x=> new SampleModel
                          {
                                  ItemName=x.Key.ItemName,
                                  ItemNo=x.Key.ItemNo }).Tolist(); **                 when i use this line ** Group1=x.Where(y=>y.GroupName=="Group1").FirstOrDefault(), ** Getting Object Reference not sent to an instance of an object error.

Comment: This code is my past answer. You check current code

Comment: Thank you :-) It's Working now. It was data issue before

Comment: Hi Sorry too trouble you again. i have edited my question. item 3 and item 4 has data only for 2 batches so in this scenario i am getting **Getting Object Reference not sent to an instance of an object error**  please suggest me on this.

Comment: @RajeswariML  are you sure your code with my answer is the same ?

Comment: yes it is same.only in second select i am using like this for all the batches **Group1=x.Group1==null?0:x.Group1,**  because Group1.ItemQty was not coming.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = context.Batch
    .GroupBy(i => new {i.ItemName, i.ItemNo})
    .Select(g => new {
        ItemName = g.Key.ItemName,
        ItemNo = g.Key.ItemNo,
        Group1 = g.Where(i => i.GroupName == “Group1”).First().ItemQty,
        Group2 = g.Where(i => i.GroupName == “Group2”).First().ItemQty,
        Group3 = g.Where(i => i.GroupName == “Group3”).First().ItemQty,
        Group4 = g.Where(i => i.GroupName == “Group4”).First().ItemQty
    })
    .Where(i => i.GroupName != “”);
```

Comment: At run time getting this Exception : Sequence contains no elements even though context.Batch has all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ItemNo", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ItemQty", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("GroupName", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Pen",234, 2, "Group1"}); 
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Pen",234, 4, "Group2"}); 
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Pen",234, 6, "Group3"}); 
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Pen",234, 3, "Group4"}); 
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"item2",365, 3, "Group1"}); 
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"item2",365, 5, "Group2"}); 
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"item2",365, 2, "Group3"}); 
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"item2",365, 3, "Group4"});

            List<string> groupNames = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("GroupName")).Distinct().ToList();

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
            pivot.Columns.Add("ItemNo", typeof(int));
            foreach (string groupName in groupNames)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add(groupName, typeof(string));
            }

            var items = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("ItemName"));

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                DataRow pivotRow = pivot.Rows.Add();
                pivotRow["ItemName"] = item.First().Field<string>("ItemName");
                pivotRow["ItemNo"] = item.First().Field<int>("ItemNo");
                foreach (var group in item)
                {
                    pivotRow[group.Field<string>("GroupName")] = group.Field<int>("ItemQty");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. will try this logic and let you know.  I am using Odata Service to get the data from Database(Microsoft Dynamic Nav). so first i am getting the resutl to List<SampleModel> . then i am trying to extract the the data from it.

Comment: Is the database on a SQL Server?  If so you can bypass the Dynamic Nav interface and extra data directly from the server.

Comment: the data is in Dynamic Nav. we are accessing it over OData Service. To the list i am getting all the data from there i have to filter.

Comment: I believve the OData Service is just an interface to a SQL Server Application.  Your Class SampleModel doesn't agree with the Table Contents .  Having four properties Group1, Group2, Group3, Group4 will return 4 columns while your table has a single column "GroupName".  My solution is using a single column GrouypName.  Is there a way of getting one column instead of 4?